# Cleared Set in the Child Process

Tags: linux, callback, fork, trace, intel-pin

I have a multiprocess application and I trace it in `Pin` using the `follow_execv` switch. To put it simply, there exists a `fork` in the program. Before the `fork` occurs, I create a set and make some insertions. Right after `fork`, because of the `follow_execv` switch, an extra copy of my `pintool` is created and executed. Both the parent and child `pintools` contain the **same** contents. But after the [FOLLOW_CHILD_PROCESS_CALLBACK](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/group__CHILD__PROCESS__API.html#gab109395d5b4fa72f83efaf0a449c340b) is called, the set in the child becomes **empty**. Why is this happening?

P.S.: The program is `gimp`. It is both **multiprocess** and **multithreaded**. Are there any limitations for these kinds of programs in `Pin`?

Comment: Just some ideas... Is Intel's Pin library fork safe? If it is, then it could be the Pin library has an `at_fork` handler that clears the state of the child on fork.

Comment: In fact, only part of the state is cleared. I have a counter variable in the parent the value of which remains intact in the child!

Comment: @jww, it was a good hint. I mmaped a shared page to avoid possible Pin initialization mess.

Comment: Well, I think that I should give up on `shared memory`. They are also removed by `Pin`, after each `fork`. It seems that using `files` to share data between parent and child `pintools` is the last solution.